# React prevent re render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

How should I prevent a re render when I click on onClose to close the modal.

It looks like the dispatch function: dispatch(setActiveStep(0) cause some troubles.

```
export default function ImportOrderModal(props: ImportOrderModalProps) {
  const { open, onClose } = props
  const {
    orderImport: { activeStep }
  } = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state)
  const steps = useImportOrderConfig()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getOrdersList()
  }, [])

  const onCloseModal = () => {
    onClose()
    // Force a re render because of activeStep value
    dispatch(setActiveStep(0))
  }

  const getOrdersList = async () => {
    const orders = //API call        
    dispatch(setOrdersList(orders))
  }


  return (
    <Modal open={open} onClose={onCloseModal}>
        <Stepper steps={steps} currentStepNumber={activeStep} />
        <FormSteps />
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Comment: ***Why*** are you trying to prevent rerenders? Is there any current issue with the way React is running your app? Can you [edit] the post to include more details about any specific issue and why you think preventing rerenders is a valid solution?

Answer (score 1):

This block is outside of your useEffect()

```
const getOrdersList = async () => {
  const orders = //API call
  dispatch(setOrdersList(orders))
}
```

This will cause rendering troubles.

if you're using an older version of React (<17) that doesn't enforce <React.StrictMode> you can get away with rewriting that as:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getOrderList
    .then((orders) => dispatch(setOrdersList(orders))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}, [dispatch]);
```

if you're using a newer version of React (>18) you will have to cleanup your asynchronous call in the cleanup function of your useEffect().

```
useEffect(() => {
  // This has to be passed down to your fetch/axios call
  const controller = new AbortController();

  getOrderList(controller)
    .then((orders) => dispatch(setOrdersList(orders))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));

  return () => {
    // This will abort any ongoing async call
    controller.abort();
  }
}, [dispatch]);
```

For this to make sense I will probably have to write an example of the api call for you as well, if you don't mind I'll use axios for the example but it essentially works the same-ish with .fetch.

```
const getOrderList = async (controller) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get("url", { signal: controller.signal });
    return data.orders;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```